# how to use dynamic variable in update.js shopify

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, shopify

I want yo use  test variable in update.js but it shows error when I use as variable but when I pass this value directly it works
can someone please tell me how can use dynamic variable to change quantity of existing products in cart

I have updated my code It will allow user to add only 5 items more than 5 items will be removed It will create string which will look like this
32082238341235:0,39470423048307:0,32164693278835:0,32164693835891:1

and finally the all IDs and qunatity will be updated by update.js

I have got error in last step its shows
{"status":404,"message":"Cart Error","description":"Cannot find variant"}

when i try to update all products

```js
jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
  var items_new = cart.items;
  var count = 0;
  count = cart.item_count;
  var item_to_remove = count - 5;

  if (count > 5) {
    var item_to_remove = count - 5;
    var combine = ""
    if (item_to_remove > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items_new.length; i++) {
        if (count > 5) {
          var c_id = items_new[i].variant_id;
          var c_quantity = items_new[i].quantity;

          if (c_quantity >= item_to_remove) {


            var q = c_quantity - item_to_remove
            var data_multiple = c_id + ":" + q + ",";


            debugger;



            count = count - item_to_remove;
            console.log(data_multiple);
            var combine = combine + data_multiple;

          } else {

            var data_single = c_id + ":" + 0 + ",";

            count = count - c_quantity;
            item_to_remove = item_to_remove - c_quantity
            console.log(data_single)

            var combine = combine + data_single;
          }

        }

      }


      console.log(combine.slice(0, -1));
      var test = combine.slice(0, -1);

      console.log({
        updates: {
          test
        }
      });
      jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {
        updates: {
          test
        }
      });





    }
    t._rerenderCart()

  }
  t.sidebarDrawer.open()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is this getJSON function being called from?

Comment: @kiner_shah It is shopify's default It will get all cart data

Comment: Looks like you're building up a string in the `combine` variable, which eventually ends up as the `test` variable. As a result, `test` is _a string_ like `"794864229:0,794864101:5"`. You'd need it to be an actual object instead. Also, doing `{ updates: { test } }` is a shorthand for `{ updates: { test: "whatever the value of test is" } }` and not the same as `{ updates: test }`. (This is relevant since `test` isn't a valid `variant_id`.) As it is now, you'd get output like `{ updates: { test: "794864229:0,794864101:5" } }`.

Comment: Exactly as @natancodes pointed out, you should pass a proper object to updates, not a string.

Comment: I got value in my test variable but I can not update the values

Comment: @natancodes
how can I pass object can you please show me little example

Comment: I'd approach it by changing the line `var combine = ""` to `var combine = {}`. Going from there, instead of constructing the strings like `data_multiple`, you could then assign properties to the object, like `combine[c_id] = q`.

Comment: ok I will try to pass object instead of string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `test` as an object within parentheses `{}` and then pass to `updates` by using the spread `...` operator.

```js
var test = {39470423048307 : 0, 32164693278835 : 0, 32164693835891 : 1};
console.log({updates: {...test}});
jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates:{...test}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In your updated code, you are passing a string to `updates` rather than an object. You should create an object from the data inside the for loop and pass that object to `updates`. See lines with `// CHANGE HERE`:

```
...
var combine = {};
if (item_to_remove > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items_new.length; i++) {
    if (count > 5) {
      var c_id = items_new[i].variant_id;
      var c_quantity = items_new[i].quantity;

      if (c_quantity >= item_to_remove) {


        var q = c_quantity - item_to_remove;
        
        // CHANGE HERE
        combine[c_id] = q;
        
        count = count - item_to_remove;

      } else {
        // CHANGE HERE
        combine[c_id] = 0;

        count = count - c_quantity;
        item_to_remove = item_to_remove - c_quantity;
      }
      console.log(combine);
    }

  }

  // CHANGE HERE
  var test = combine;

  console.log({
    updates: test
  });
  jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {
    updates: test
  });
...
```

Comment: Precisely so, although the spread operator isn't strictly necessary. i.e. `{ updates: test }` should work just as well.

Comment: @natancodes, ohh yes, you are right :-)

Comment: @kiner_shah  tried this  It shows {"status":404,"message":"Cart Error","description":"Cannot find variant"} Error

Comment: @natancodes, Spread operator can be useful though for example in case when updates should have some other data as well.

Comment: @Sunny, is that URL proper? It works (proceeds further), so the problem is URL which you are trying to access.

Comment: @kiner_shah
  jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', {updates:{39470423048307 : 0, 32164693278835 : 0, 32164693835891 : 1}});
If I use like this it works but in variable its not working

Comment: @Sunny, is the server side code owned by you? If yes, please update your question and include server side code as well.

Comment: @kiner_shah I have updated my code please see

Comment: @Sunny, please check my updated answer if it works for you.

Comment: @kiner_shah hey bro can you please help me with this questionhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274760/how-to-add-multiple-items-in-shopify-cart